# For which applications is the Theorem of existence of a minimizer in a infinite dimensional Hilbert space relevant?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

I am thinking about the Theorem of existence of a minimizer for a infinite dimensional Hilbert space.
My question: why it is so important? why working in a infinite dimensional setting (in this case Hilbert space) is important (especially from the viewpoint of the applications)?

I am sorry for the naive question, but I am really interested in that.

I hope someone could help me and give some references about the importance of this Theorem (in a infinite dimensional Hilbert space) for applications.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: well, the proof (as presented in Rudin's RCA) of Riesz's representation theorem that $x\mapsto \langle \cdot, x\rangle$ being a conjugate-linear isomorphism of $H$ onto $H^*$ atleast implicitly uses the existence of a minimizer. This is clearly a very important fact about Hilbert spaces, which makes it much nicer than general Banach spaces/other topological vector spaces. The whole Dirac Bra-Ket formalism of quantum mechanics relies on this identification.

Comment: @peek-a-boo nice comment, thank you very much!

Comment: Infinite dimensional settings are function spaces, so if you want to find a function that minimizes or maximizes some criteria (e.g. Calculus of Variations), the existence of minimizers and maximizers is crucial.

Comment: @rubikscube09 could you please better explain?

Comment: @C.Bishop - sure, what specifically was unclear?

Comment: @rubikscube09 what does it mean "minimize or maximize some criteria"?

Comment: @C.Bishop - you are often looking for a function $f$ that minimizes some quantity or functional, e.g. find a function $f$ such that $\int_U |\nabla f|^2$ is minimal. This is because minimizes these quantities is often equivalent to solving a PDE, e.g. if you minimize some quantity you also solve a PDE. Thus, solutions to PDE (which are important to some mathematicians) are sometimes given by functions that minimize some criterion. You can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation for a more physical explanation.